# C# Get NZEC error parsing input on HackerEarth

Tags: c#

I want to learn C# so I started to use hackerearth and solve problems from their website but I got into some kind of problem. So I have the following code

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long N, i, answer = 1;
            do
            {
                N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            } while (N < 1 && N > 1000);

            long[] A = new long[N];

            for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                do
                {
                    A[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                } while (A[i] < 1 && A[i] > 1000);
            }

            for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                answer = (answer * A[i]) % (1000000007);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(answer);
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile it I get the correct answer and everything it's fine but when I submit it to hackerearth compiler it gives me the NZEC error. I thought I'm missing something since I just started C# some days ago so I wrote it again but in C++ and it gave me the maximum score on the website. I know that there might be some problems in my variable declarations since I didn't understand exactly how to read numbers and I hope you can help me solve this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Any time you get an error you should tell us the error.

Comment: I told you the error. I got the runtime error NZEC when I submitted the code written in C#.

Comment: What? Could you explain me how to write the correct statement?
And w/ the exact same condition I got maximum score in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are stuck on the [Find Product problem](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/practice-problems/algorithm/find-product/), as you've suspected, the input of the data is one line for N, and then one line for ALL N numbers that you need to multiply, separated by a space. You can parse the line of numbers quickly with LINQ (I would suggest you get stuck into LINQ as quickly as possible - this will get you away from the C++ imperative mindset).

How about:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // Less than 2^31 integers to be read
            var A = Console.ReadLine() // Read the line of space delimited numbers
                .Split(' ') // Split out by the separator
                .Select(n => Convert.ToInt64(n)) // Parse each number to long
                .ToArray(); // Convert to a materialized array

            Debug.Assert(A.Length == N, "Site lied to us about N numbers");

            long answer = 1; // or var answer = 1L;
            for(var i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                answer = (answer * A[i]) % (1000000007);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(answer);
        }
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- The `do..while` has no effect - they will always exit after one pass - this because a value cannot be < 1 and > 1000 simultaneously
- Note that `Convert.ToInt32` parses a 32 bit int. You've defined a long (which is ALWAYS 64 bit in C#, unlike C++), so this should be `Convert.ToInt64`
- The problem does however constrain `A[i]` under 10 ^ 3, so `A[]` can be int[], although the product could be larger, so `long` or even `System.Numerics.BigInteger` can be used for the product.
- NZEC is a site specific error - it means the app crashed with a non zero process ecit code. The site also prints the actual error and stack trace further down the page.

Since you say you want to learn C# (and not just convert C code to C#), you can also LINQify the final for loop which calculates the answer from the array using [.Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Aggregate supports both a seeded overload (i.e. a `left fold`, as it allows the return type to differ), and an unseeded overload (i.e. `reduce` where the return type must be the same as the input enumerable). In your case, you don't actually need to seed the answer with `1L` since it can be seeded with `A[0]` and the next multiplication will be with `A[1]` since any number multiplied by 1 will be number.

```
var answer = A.Aggregate((subtotal, next) => (subtotal * next) % (1000000007));
```